# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat Laravel mix bug

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, laravel-mix

I have a tiered folder structure with stylesheets and script files. I need to keep the same structure in the output folder. For all scripts and styles, I get an array of paths, convert them and give them to the mix.

The problem is that the mix accepts my paths but doesn't create the desired structure. Previously I did the array of paths manually, now I am not getting the right one. There are no compiler errors. I still use `mix.js(str, str2)` and `mix.less(str, str2)`

The paths I received are similar to those that I wrote manually

[My config](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-banach-y66o85?file=/webpack.mix.js)

But if I start the nodejs debugging process, then I will see

[image]

My folder structure

[image]

My array of js paths

Less array the same as js

[image]

[image]

i still dont get my files, but debug error is disappear

```js
let compileJS = (str, str2) => {
    console.log(str,str2)
    mix.js(str, str2);
};

glob("./components/**/*.js", (err, files) => {
    files.map((p) => {
        pathsJS.push({
            in: p,
            out: p.replace("./components/", "./dist/views/"),
        });
    });
  //  console.log(pathsJS);
    pathsJS.map((p) => {
        compileJS(p.in, p.out);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that all libraries by default make the issuance of paths an asynchronous method. Mix works synchronously. I installed a faster version of the plugin, did the output of paths with synchronous and placed the mix function in the same function. Thus, the code is executed at once.

```js
const glob = require("fast-glob");


let compile = () => {
    function getFilesJS(baseSrc) {
        return glob.sync("./components/**/*.js", {
            onlyFiles: true,
        });
    }
    let filesjs = getFilesJS();
    filesjs.map((p) => {
        pathsJS.push({
            in: p,
            out: p.replace("./components/", "./dist/views/"),
        });
    });

    pathsJS.map((p) => {
        mix.js(p.in, p.out);
    });
    function getFilesLESS() {
        return glob.sync("./components/**/*.less", {
            onlyFiles: true,
        });
    }
    let filesless = getFilesLESS();
    filesless.map((p) => {
        pathsLess.push({
            in: p,
            out: p.replace("./components/", "./dist/views/"),
        });
    });

    pathsLess.map((p) => {
        mix.less(p.in, p.out.replace("style.less", ""));
    });
    mix.less("./src/less/styles.less", "./dist/template_styles.css");
    mix.js("./src/js/script.js", "./dist/script.js");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was two bugs with nodejs and broken symlink to storage (after moving project folder into other place) (laravel 8). So what i've done:

1. Removed storage symlink and `php artisan storage:link`
2. Downgraded nodejs version from 18 to 14:

```
$ node -v
18.12.1
$ n 14.21.2
installed
$ node -v
14.21.2
```